# "Localization" of a module at a family of elements

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $x=(x_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of elements of a commutative ring $R$. Typically $I$ is infinite. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. For every finite subset $E \subseteq I$ define $M_E = M$, and for inclusions $E \subseteq F$ we define $M_E \to M_F$ to be the multiplication with $\prod_{i \in F \setminus E} x_i$. These maps are compatible, hence we may define the colimit
$$M x^{-1} := \varinjlim_{E \subseteq I \text{ finite}} M_E.$$
I would like to know if this $R$-module is already known and what is a standard notation for it. This module occurs naturally in the study of infinite tensor products.

When $x=(f^k)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, then I think $M x^{-1} = M[f^{-1}]$ is the usual localization.

In general, if $S$ is the multiplicative system generated by $\{x_i : i \in I\}$, we have a canonical homomorphism $M x^{-1} \to M[S^{-1}]$ which sends $m \in M_E$ to $\dfrac{m}{\prod_{i \in E} x_i}$. The image consists of those fractions whose denominators are "flat" in the sense that no $x_i^k$ with $k>1$ occurs. If $m \in M_E$ lies in the kernel, this means that $\prod_{i \in F} x_i^{k_i} \cdot  m = 0$ for some finite $E \subseteq F \subseteq I$ and $k_i \in \mathbb{N}^+$. I don't see any reason why this should imply $\prod_{i \in G} x_i \cdot m = 0$ for some $E \subseteq G$, which would mean that $m$ represents zero in the colimit $M x^{-1}$. Thus, in general, I think that $M x^{-1}$ doesn't embed into $M[S^{-1}]$. When all $x_i$ are $M$-regular, then it embeds.

Comment: Is $R x^{-1}$ a ring?  Is $M x^{-1}$ a module over it?  If so, then I'd guess you're localizing at some Gabriel filter.

Comment: It is not a ring.